# Zoom an ImageView Image in Single UIScrollView in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiscrollview

I am a newbie in iOS Development I want to Zoom a `UIImageView` image in `UIScrolView`  for that I added my `UIImageView` in `UIView` and then I added my `UIView` in to `UIScrollView` but it does not show any image on the View. Following is my code

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];
    self.viewImages=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(index*bigimage.frame.size.width, 0, bigimage.frame.size.width, bigimage.frame.size.height)];
    bigImage=[[UIImageView alloc]init];
    bigImage.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    bigImage.tag=123;
    bigImage.tag=index;
    bigImage.userInteractionEnabled=TRUE;
    bigImage.frame=CGRectMake(index * self.viewImages.frame.size.width, 0, self.viewImages.frame.size.width, self.viewImages.frame.size.height);
    [bigImage setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];
    [bigImage sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:image] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"]];
    [bigImage setUserInteractionEnabled:TRUE];
    [self.objectarray insertObject:bigImage atIndex:index];
    [self.viewImages addSubview:bigImage];
    [self.viewImages addSubview:[self.objectarray objectAtIndex:index]];
    [self.zoomScroll addSubview:self.viewImages];
    self.zoomScroll.contentSize=self.viewImages.frame.size;
```

Please give me solution for zooming `UIScrolView` image and add my all array of images in to my `UIScrolView`. Here big image is my `UIImageView` and `self.viewImages` is my `UIView`.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to make a horizontal scroller of images with zoom functionality on each image.

Create a custom view named SlideshowImageView with XIB file and drop UIScrollView on it add the following code in SlideshowImageView.h

```
@interface SlideshowImageView : UIView <UIScrollViewDelegate>
{
    UIImageView *imageView;   
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *zoomScrollView;
@end
```

Link UIScrollView with the property name zoomScrollView and the scrollview delegates as well.

Now add the following code in SlideshowImageView.m

```
@implementation SlideshowImageView

- (void)setImageForSlide:(UIImage *)image 
{
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    imageView.userInteractionEnabled = TRUE;
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
    imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    [self.zoomScrollView addSubview:imageView];
}

@end
```

Implement the following UIScrollview delegate in SlideshowImageView.m:

```
- (UIView *) viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    return imageView;
}
```

Now from the controller in which you are creating views using loop you can do like this:

```
for(int index=0; index < [self.imagesa count]; index++)
{
    NSDictionary *dict=[self.imagesa objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *image=[dict valueForKey:@"link"];

    //Create custom view now and add it into your main scrollview
    SlideshowImageView *iView = [[SlideshowImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(index*mainScrollView.frame.size.width, 0, mainScrollView.frame.size.width, mainScrollView.frame.size.height)];
    [iView setImageForSlide: [UIImage imageNamed:image]];
    [self.mainScrollView addSubview:iView];
}
```

Do let me know if you have any confusions regarding the implementation.